# Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Non-static method Conexion::conectar() cannot be called

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mvc, conexión

Hola estoy tratando de conectarme a la base de datos siguiendo el modelo mvc pero me da el siguiente error, aqui agrego el codigo del login del controlador del modulo y la conexión, espero que me puedan ayudar y tambien sirva de ayuda para otras personas que les da el mismo error

Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Non-static method Conexion::conectar() cannot be called

el  login

```
      <form action="inicio" method="post">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="ingUsuario" required>
          
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="ingPassword" required>
          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
         
         <?php

      $login = new ControladorUsarios();
      $login -> ctrIngresoUsuario();

     ?>

       
      
      </form>
```

aqui agrego el controlador  para que me ayuden a detectar el error

```
// Ingreso de usuario//

class ControladorUsarios{

    public function ctrIngresoUsuario()
    {

    if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"]))
        {
    
    if (preg_match('/^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) && preg_match('/^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])) {
                
                $tabla = "usuarios";
                $item = "usuario";
                $valor = $_POST["ingUsuario"];

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlmostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

                var_dump($respuesta);



            }


        }
}
}
```

aqui agrego el EL MODELO para que me ayuden a detectar el error

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios{

    public static function MdlmostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor){

$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
$stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> execute();

return $stmt -> fetch();


    }

}
```

aqui agrego la conexion para que me ayuden a detectar el error

```
class Conexion{

    public function conectar(){

        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=posmax","root","");

        $link->exec("set names utf8");

        return $link;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a alguien de esta comunidad pude darme cuenta que la solución era agregar static en la funtion conectar() quedo asi

````
class Conexion{

    public static function conectar(){

        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=posmax","root","");

        $link->exec("set names utf8");

        return $link;

    }

}```
````

Comment: O en lugar de hacer la función estática puedes crear un objeto instanciado de la clase y acceder luego al método

Comment: Mas o menos como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Puedes buscar en internet como crear la instancia de una clase, hay muchos recursos al respecto